# IntelliJ IDEA always formats one-line for statement into multi-line

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ keeps formatting this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

}
```

into this:

```java
for (int i = 0;
     i < 10;
     i++) {

}
```

I prefer the first style(one-line statement) than the second. I tried many methods but failed, please help me.

Comment: Please detailed the methods you tried that did not work, because otherwise its possible that we will suggest you solutions that you tried. Try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html

Comment: @OmriAttiya thanks your advice. I will take it next time.

Comment: @VinQin, if my answer is correct, please mark it as the answer to make it easier for people to find it in the future.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi yes, thanks your answer. I thought the system will accept the best answer automatically since I am a newbie in this site. Sorry for that.

Comment: @VinQin No worries, just wanted to let you know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change this by going to your Preferences (`Command-,` on Mac) Go to

`Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces`.

Find `for() statement` in the list. Next to `for() statement`, you may see `always wrap`, click this and change it to `Do not wrap`.

Answer (score 1):

I also found a solution for this.

The problem is caused by the android style.
Go to `Settings/Editor/Live templates/` select `Android/foreach` and uncheck the checkbox `Reformat according to style` in the lower right corner.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

go to setting->code-style->java and check everything looks great there.

**Edited**

[for loop setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV6th.png)

Check for For Loop Setting

Comment: What does "check everything looks great there" mean? What should OP be looking for?

Comment: The answer goes in the right direction, but you could provide a screenshot and more detailed information when you get to the Code Style screen.